# Angular fails to receive the JWT token from Spring Boot

Tags: angular, spring-security, jwt

I am getting this error in console:

```
null
dan
TypeError: Cannot read property 'token' of null
at MapSubscriber.project (basic-authentication.service.ts:29)
at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:29)
at MapSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:35)
at MapSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
at FilterSubscriber._next (filter.js:33)
at FilterSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (mergeMap.js:69)
at InnerSubscriber._next (InnerSubscriber.js:11)
at InnerSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
```

I am trying to authenticate a user from Angular 7 front end. When I did the tests with Postman it worked perfectly for all requests(even with JWT token).

I ran again the login operation with debugger enabled on intelliJ and the JWT was created correctly and sent, but it appears to be null on Angular frontend app.

***Note that I am, maybe, intermediate in Spring, but really novice in Angular

This is my **Angular code** getting called:

```
    executeJWTAuthenticationService(username, password) {
    return this.http.post<any>(
      `${API_URL}/login`, {
        username,
        password
      }).pipe(
        map(
          data => {
            console.log(data);
            console.log(username);
            sessionStorage.setItem(AUTHENTICATED_USER, username);
            sessionStorage.setItem(TOKEN, `Bearer ${data.token}`);
            return data;
          }
        )
      );
  }
```

This is my **JwtAuthenticationFilter**:

```
    public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public JwtAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    /* Trigger when we issue POST request to /login
    We also need to pass in {"username":"dan", "password":"dan123"} in the request body
     */
    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {

        // Grab credentials and map them to login viewmodel
        LoginViewModel credentials = null;
        try {
            credentials = new ObjectMapper().readValue(request.getInputStream(), LoginViewModel.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Create login token
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                credentials.getUsername(),
                credentials.getPassword(),
                new ArrayList<>());

        // Authenticate user
        Authentication auth = authenticationManager.authenticate(authenticationToken);

        return auth;
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // Grab principal
        UserPrincipal principal = (UserPrincipal) authResult.getPrincipal();

        // Create JWT Token
        String token = JWT.create()
                .withSubject(principal.getUsername())
                .withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + JwtProperties.EXPIRATION_TIME))
                .sign(HMAC512(JwtProperties.SECRET.getBytes()));

        // Add token in response
        response.addHeader(JwtProperties.HEADER_STRING, JwtProperties.TOKEN_PREFIX + token);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe try `{username: username, password: password}` as object?

Comment: @Fussel Do I need commas like "username":"username"? (again, new to Angular)

Comment: Well acutally you probably need something like `return this.http.post(
      \`${API_URL}/login\`, JSON.stringify({username: username,password: password}), [...]` assuming your API works with JSON (in that case you should also set the content-type header) and no in JS/TS you don't need "username" in commas because first is the property of the object and the second is your parameter variable.

Comment: It looks like your API simply isn't sending anything back to the front end. Now I don't know Spring at all: is it possible that Spring is reacting weirdly because of the browser's pre-flight OPTIONS request? Are you handling CORS?

Comment: Your back seems to return jwt token as header but you try to read it from body in angular. Try to add token to your body response in spring or parse header in angular

Comment: @MartinChoraine that sounds about right. Any tips on how to fix that ?

Comment: @WillAlexander I have a CORS configuration class in my Spring Boot project so it is handled

Comment: To read header in angular look at response type in httpclient : `response`

Comment: I've not my laptop now I can check later

Comment: I am getting this when I look into network -> Response Headers :  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJkYW4iLCJleHAiOjE1NjUzNjgwMDF9.80dRpHI2x6fY1F43pkYOySlZxbuXU9xY2_UAeUmE2x5_31MApEyGha1c3U5Jcy-EH2SrUDr4G-8sjk6_RiEZRw
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Length: 0
Date: Tue, 30 Jul 2019 16:26:41 GMT
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response

Comment: @MartinChoraine You were correct about reading the body instead of the header. I have added the code that solved my problem as an answear

Comment: @MartinChoraine I was wrong. It would let me log in, but when I look inside session storage the username is correct, but token is "Bearer undefined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to observe reponse in your angular http call.
Then you will be able to read JWT token from response headers.

```
executeJWTAuthenticationService(username, password) {
    return this.http.post<any>(
        `${API_URL}/login`, {
            username,
            password
        }, {observe: 'response'}).pipe(
        map(
            data => {
                const token = data.headers.get("Authorization");
                console.log(data);
                console.log(username);
                sessionStorage.setItem(AUTHENTICATED_USER, username);
                sessionStorage.setItem(TOKEN, `Bearer ${token}`);
                return data;
            }
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: If you want to find more information how connect spring security with angular to authenticate with JWT, I suggest you to look at JHipster implementation. You will learn a lot of stuffs : https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app

Comment: Thanks! I solved the problem eventually, but forgot about this post. I started playing with `data.headers` and `console.log` and figured out I should use `data.headers.get('authorization')` . This si the code that worked for me:

Comment: `executeJWTAuthenticationService(username, password) {
    return this.http.post<any>(
      `${API_URL}/login`, {
        username,
        password
      },
      {
        observe: 'response'
      }).pipe(
        map(
          data => {
            sessionStorage.setItem(AUTHENTICATED_USER, username);
            sessionStorage.setItem(TOKEN, data.headers.get('authorization'));
            return data;
          }
        )
      );
  }`   , sorry I don't know how to edit the code in a comment